# Java Swing Null Pointer Exception in Netbeans IDE

Tags: java, swing, nullpointerexception

I'm still fairly new to Java and I've started on a simple GUI project with the netbeans java IDE 8.2 using swing and am running into a null pointer exception.

I've removed the majority of the code down to the bottom portion in order to try and find where the issue is coming from and I still get an exception running only these lines of code.

```
package finalmodel;
import javax.swing.*;


public class FinalModel extends JFrame {

    public static void main (String[] args) {

        new FinalModel();
    }

    public FinalModel () {

        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);

    }

}
```

The application runs fine, and as far as I can tell, the exception doesn't affect functionality (a window pops up and can be successfully closed from the above code), but the exception is thrown upon the window's closure.

The stack trace given to me by the IDE is

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: peer
    at sun.awt.windows.WInputMethod.openCandidateWindow(Native Method)
    at sun.awt.windows.WInputMethod.access$400(WInputMethod.java:45)
    at sun.awt.windows.WInputMethod$1.run(WInputMethod.java:602)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:90)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:733)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:730)
    at org.netbeans.core.TimableEventQueue.dispatchEvent(TimableEventQueue.java:159) [catch]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:205)    
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)    
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)    
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)    
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

[Version Info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2FUTo.png)

Comment: Looks more like a NetBeans problem than Swing... Try to copy paste your code in a *non-GUI* project and see if it still NPE.

Comment: for clarification, what version of java are you using for this? i'd like to try and replicate it on my system.

Comment: @EvOlaNdLuPiZ I've added a picture with all of the version info.

Comment: @Matthieu Sorry if this is a dumb question, but how would I go about running this GUI related code in a non-GUI project?

Comment: @Omar, Java is Java :) Just create a "regular" project and make your class extend `JFrame`. You just won't have the NetBeans WYSIWYG editor that might get in the way.

Answer (score 0):

your example is very minimal. it might be missing some properties. give this a try:

```
package finalmodel;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class FinalModel extends JFrame {
 public FinalModel () {
   setTitle("setTitle()");
   setSize(300, 200);
   setLocationRelativeTo(null);
   setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
 }
 public static void main(String[] args) {
   FinalModel fm = new FinalModel ();
   fm.setVisible(true);
 }
}
```

here's a good article on jframe, for practice [jframes](https://javatutorial.net/swing-jframe-basics-create-jframe)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've tried adding more properties and even copy-pasted the code you had replied with, but I still get the same behavior. A functional window pops up and an exception is thrown when it is closed.

Comment: The code you show runs OK for me, without throwing any exceptions. Are you sure you are executing that code, and not some previous version?  (NOTE: You should be executing the GUI portion on the EventDispatchThread, not the main thread).

Comment: i'd like to suggest adding a WindowListener, [reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/windowlistener.html) , this will be useful for debug. in particular the methods windowClosing() windowClosed()

Comment: @FredK Yes, I've even created a new project entirely and placed this code in it and still get the same thing. As I've mentioned before, the code seems to run fine and the window pops up as expected, the exception is only thrown when the program closes. Since it seems to run fine for you, could this just be an issue with netbeans as mentioned above by someone else above?

Comment: @Omar it's simple but worth a shot, try re-installing netbeans. let us know what the results are.

Answer (score 0):

Netbeans bug! Reinstall Netbeans with un updated version or something like that.